# Folder permissions through powershell

Tags: active-directory, powershell-2.0, file-permissions, user-permissions

im trying to set some rights on a newly created user in AD.
After I have created the folder, I try to set the various rights like this:

```
$Rights = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]::FullControl
$Inherit = @([System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]::ContainerInherit,[System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]::ObjectInherit)
$Propagation = [System.Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags]::None
$Access =[System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]::Allow
$ACL = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount "localdomain\$userprincipalname"
$objACE = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($ACL, $Rights, $Inherit, $Propagation, $Access)                     
$ACL = Get-Acl -Path $userDir
$ACL.AddAccessRule($objACE) 
Set-ACL -Path $userDir -AclObject $ACL
```

The error I get is related to the parameters i pass to AddAccessRule

```
Exception calling "AddAccessRule" with "1" argument(s): "Some or all identity references could not be translated."
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

But I cannot see any error here, so I would really appreciate another set of eyes.

Comment: Have you checked the value of `$userprincipalname`? maybe isn't correct?

Comment: Yes, both `$userprincipalname` and `$userDir` are correct as specified earlier in the script.

Comment: I can say that your code in my domain works giving at `$userprincipalname` an existing samUserName and an existing path to `$userDir`.

Comment: I think i just messed up some parameter somewhere, I got it working.
As this is not really a qustion/answerthread - should I delete it?

Comment: @Alexander nope, just post an answer yourself and accept it. The question has a useful code sample and should be kept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so my solution works, and as far as I can find, is the way to set rights on a folder.

```
$Rights = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]::FullControl
$Inherit = @([System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]::ContainerInherit,[System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]::ObjectInherit)
$Propagation = [System.Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags]::None
$Access =[System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]::Allow
$ACL = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount "localdomain\$userprincipalname"
$objACE = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($ACL, $Rights,$Inherit, $Propagation, $Access)                     
$ACL = Get-Acl -Path $userDir
$ACL.AddAccessRule($objACE) 
Set-ACL -Path $userDir -AclObject $ACL
```